# Installing python versions 3.3.x return seg fault 11 after updating gcc

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew

I have the latest Xcode CLI tools installed but I used homebrew to update gcc to 4.8.1. Python's 2.x through 3.2.x still install fine but pythons 3.3.x fail. I see other issues reported on stackoverflow indicating the fix is to install Xcode CLI's.

Before I dig a bigger hole, can someone say whether I should brew uninstall gcc or reinstall CLI or is their a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Homebrew does not update gcc but adds another one alsoI think it will still use the Xcode llvm to compile python

Comment: I used brew tap homebrew/versions

Comment: Hm, gcc still points to llvm-gcc-4.2 but that file has a date of July 12, 2013. I also used homebrew to update gfortran. Might this cause the problem?

Comment: Homebrew also only writes to /usr/local so /usr/bin/gcc will be Apple supplied